# Express dynamic routings on root

Tags: javascript, express

I'm building a new App and my Boss asked me to generate this kind of urls structure to search for different items by:

- `xyz.com/<techs>`
- `xyz.com/<locaions>`
- `xyz.com/<sectors>`

As you can see it would result in having 3 different dynamic urls on the same level of root:

```
app.get('/', homeController.index);
...
app.get(':locations', locationsController.getLocations);
app.get(':techs', techsController.getTechs);
app.get(':sectors', sectorsController.getSectors);
...
```

Obviously trying this approach I end up generating only bugs and by my point of view this is something not possible to achieve. Am I wrong? My Boss is pretty sure that it is possible... if yes, how?

Comment: Instead of `:location` make it `/location` similarly for all .

Comment: Unfortunately that `:locations` could be: London, Leeds, Manchester, etc... My obvious solution would be `/locations/:location` but he doesn't like it.......

Comment: Is your boss happy with `/:route?params=location` ? :p

Comment: you will have to mention '/:route', and tokenize the route... for ex: if link is xyz.com/London/news then after tokenizing, your first param you can match against a list of countries, or list of sectors, or list of techs, and call the corresponding controller

Comment: you can try using regex to match everything and handle redirections yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.get('/:route', (req, res) => {
  // to the name the name of the route parameter.
  let route = req.params.route;
  if (route === 'tech') {
    // do sth
  } else if (route === 'location') {
    // do sth
  } else {
    // do sth.
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This looks like a single route targeting a static `:route` while for example: `:locations` could be: London, Leeds, Manchester, etc... All those 3 levels contains different dynamic urls...

Comment: that means for every top level url, you have to define an explicit route like `/locations/:locations` or you could use the above method and check for the names of the params if you know all of them. `if (route === 'london')`.